# Script stoping with no error when parsing a mail attachment of 3 MB

Tags: php

I am having troubles with a email parser when a attachment larger than 2MB is being encoded in base64.

The encoder I am using is called  mime_parser.php made by Manuel Lemos http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3169-PHP-Decode-MIME-e-mail-messages.html

This is the part of my code where the script just stops and prints only half of `var_dump`, it's like the script timed out:

```
$parameters2=array('File'=>$message_file,'SaveBody'=>'tmp/','SkipBody'=>1);
                echo "<div style='display: none;'>";
                $success2 = $mime->Decode($parameters2, $decoded2);             
                echo "</div>";

                $mime->Analyze($decoded2[0], $results);
```

I also added this lines at the top of the code to ensure that there is no time limit or memory limit and I am positive that there is no `safe_mode on` on the server

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("memory_limit","1024M");
error_reporting(-1);
```

Also no errors/notice/warnings are reported. Anyone has any idea on what to check to make this work ?

Comment: I had added a var_dump right after </div> echo and the script stops when printing the `var_dump($decoded2)` in the middle of the process.

Comment: That is strange. Can you give us an example of your message file?

Comment: This is an example of output from the var_dump:
`array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["Headers"]=> array(25) { ["received:"]=> array(6) { [0]`
As you can see it's incomplete.

Comment: Can you please try to use ob_start(); before var_dump() and ob_end_flush(); after it? It will help me to understand if var_dump really fails or not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that "upload_max_filesize" is set large enough in your php.ini file to support the filesizes you are attempting to attach.

Comment: Thanks Jim but the file is being uploaded because it prints on screen the file encoded in base64 and the function `Decode()` finish successfully but dies in the middle of `var_dump`.